# angular currency filters in indian format

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I am working on angular based application, its a financial application. In which, I need to display numbers in currency format in dynamic html. Below is the way I have used for this requirement :

```
$filter('currency')(amount)
```

it is working fine but it is showing number in US format but I need to display number in indian format.

```
Example : var amount = 100000
```

If I am going with above way then number is displayed as `100,000.`

Desired Output: `1,00,000`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: pls refer this link http://fiddle.jshell.net/creekworm/M83uK/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Number.Prototype.toLocaleString() and as your indian you can use it directly,but if you have to specify format ,specify it as Number("100000").toLocaleString('en-IN')

check the following snippet

```js
console.log(Number("100000").toLocaleString('en-IN'));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the usual "won't work on internet explorer 10 or earlier" caveats apply

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Html

```
{{amount | currency:"₹":0}}
```

please refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: thanks.. this solution will definitely work with html.. but i need solution with javascript.

Comment: @vivek, you inject the filter in controller then using these filter, ex: $filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)

Comment: I already injected that filter in controller but can you please tell me what exactly i need to do .. i mean what would be value of symbol and fractionSize if I want the value as 1,00,000.

Answer (score 2):

Add this format in html {{amount | currency:"₹":0}} you can also see it on url below.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention.. i want a solution with javascript string concatenation.Like this $filter('currency')(amount)